# Swiper 10, autoplay, don't stop on click

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm trying to build marquee with the Swiper.

It works fine, but stops if clicked on the swiper, although `disableOnInteraction` is set to `false`.

I have links on some slides so I would like to be able be able to click the slides themselves but the slider shouldn't stop on click.

```js
 var swiperContainer = document.querySelector('.swiper');
    const swiper = new Swiper(swiperContainer, {
        freeMode: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        loop: true,
        loopSlides: 6,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 1,
            disableOnInteraction: false
        },
        speed: 6000,
        allowTouchMove: false,

    });
```

```css
.swiper-wrapper {
  transition-timing-function: linear !important;
}

.swiper-wrapper  {
display: flex;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: 200px;
  width :200px;
  overflow: hidden;

 

}

 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="grid-item swiper-slide">
            <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item swiper-slide">
            <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('#swiper').addEventListener('slidechangetransitionend', function(e) {
  const [swiper] = e.detail;
  swiper.autoplay.start();
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this code to the CSS:

```
.swiper-wrapper  {
  display: flex;
  pointer-events:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try remove `freeMode` options.

```
var swiperContainer = document.querySelector('.swiper');
    const swiper = new Swiper(swiperContainer, {
        autoHeight: true,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        loop: true,
        loopSlides: 6,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 1,
            disableOnInteraction: false
        },
        speed: 6000,
        allowTouchMove: false,

    });
```